# Nutch Parsing plugin and redirects

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I am using nutch 2.0, i've created a plugin for parsing html that implements Parser and works just fine.

The problem is that i need to "parse" also pages that generate redirects (301,300), for getting the url and the http code.My  plugin ignores the redirected pages.

Any ideas how i can obtain this information, maybe with other extension point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented the Protocol extension point and now i can save on database the redirects and loadtimes.